# Can I place an input element inside a select element

Tags: html

Does anyone know if I can utilize an input element for text inside of a select dropdown menu? If so then how?

```html
<select>
<input type='text' name='prdname'/>
<option>Product1</option>  
<option>Product2</option>   
<option>Product3</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Have you ever seen such a thing on the real web…? What is that supposed to look like?

Comment: Yes, in facebook search bar. It drops down but still allows for input on the top of it.

Comment: That's not a plain HTML `<select>` element, that's a very custom Javascripted thing.

Comment: so it means it can't be done...or is not allowed...

Comment: There is no "combobox" (which is what you're asking for) in plain HTML, no.